# How to show a foreign key field of a model in admin form

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In models.py I have two models created

```
class Tutor(models.Model):
...
```

```
class Case(models.Model):
    tutor_applied = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tutor,
        related_name="case_set",
        default=None,
        blank=True,
    )
```

In admin.py, I am trying something like

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    "case_set",
                ]
            },
        )
    ]
```

which does not work, showing this error

```
Unknown field(s) (case_set) specified for Tutor. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class TutorAdmin.
```

I have tried also tried:

```
class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def case_set(self):
        u = self.case_set
        if u is not None:
            return u.case_set

    fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    case_set,
                ]
            },
        )
    ]
```

which shows this error

```
sequence item 0: expected str instance, function found
```

How can I work around this to show the 'case_set' field?

I expect to see something like this in the 'Tutor' admin form, but instead with case_set

[image]

Comment: use `tutor_applied` instead of `case_set` in fields list. fields only accept class field name, not the relation name in the database

Comment: `tutor_applied` is a field of class Case, how do I reference it in class Tutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For showing reverse many to many relation ship you need to show the model which created from m2m field, it's link between your case  and tutor models:

```
class CaseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Case.tutor_applied.through


class TutorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('__all__')
    inlines = [CaseInline, ]
```

you can take a look in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models)